# Searching Twitter in the distant past

Tags: twitter, search

Is there anyway to search Twitter into the distant past. I'd like to know any occurrence of a term that was ever tweeted. It seems on http://search.twitter.com  I can only search like one week at a time.

Answer (score 1):

[Topsy](http://topsy.com/) can help you find tweets from the distant past by using their advanced search.

This search query find references to Obama in tweets between Jan/2009 & Jan/2011 -
http://topsy.com/s?mintime=1254335400&maxtime=1293820200&q=obama

Answer (score 0):

Try http://snapbird.org/ It searches terms/people all the way back to Twitter's inception.

Answer (score -4):

I only can't search because I'm using distance search. That answers it.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: very vague answer. Expand on it. for example: Make sure to clear your other search filters or something along those lines.